# Frame by frame seeking in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, media-player

In WP7 `MediaElement` allowed me to seek a frame forward or backward when the MediaElement is paused. Unfortunately in WP8 that isn't so.

So I have come to `Playerframework` by [Microsoft](https://playerframework.codeplex.com/) and hoped it could fulfill my needs.

Here the Property `SeekWhileScrubbing` convinced me to give it a try. I tested the player, but with `SeekWhileSrubbing` enabled it also doesn't work porperly to set the `Position` property. For me it looks like the player decides randomly if it updates the frame displayed or not.

I have also tried `LivePosition` Property and after that the `SeekToLive()` method but it also doesn't fix my issue.

So how can I achieve that I can seek while my playback is paused and also preview the current frame?